# Can't render variable as string in js text

Tags: php

```
let postSlug = <?= $postSlug ?? null ? "$postSlug" : 'undefined' ?>;
```

Got

```
let postSlug = eferf-1490371806;
```

expected

```
 let postSlug = "eferf-1490371806";
```

How to get correct render ? I know it's easy but my brain bugs and I get mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is interpreting the quotes, try putting them in the HTML:

```
let postSlug = "<?= $postSlug ?? null ? $postSlug : 'undefined' ?>;"
```

Or use single quotes inside the double quotes to keep it from quoting undefined:

```
let postSlug = <?= $postSlug ?? null ? "'$postSlug'" : 'undefined' ?>;
```

Comment: You answer is wrong. you missed the quotes for `undefined`. It will generate the following php error: `PHP error:  Use of undefined constant undefined - assumed 'undefined' on line 1`

Comment: second one works fine and keep quotes on both variable and undefined. Thank you.